# Shouldn't my try/except block have caught this AttributeError?

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.7 and I have a question about some code & an error that just happened.

Basically my code reads like this:

```
try:
    # Sometimes the <span> tag has a <a> tag as a child element...
    post_company = card.find("span", {"class": "company"}).find("a").decode_contents().replace("\u2026", "...")
except AttributeError:
    # ...And sometimes it doesn't.
    post_company = card.find("span", {"class": "company"}).decode_contents().replace("\u2026", "...")
```

But I still got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Roland/dir1/2020/Indeed-Scraper/database/database.py", line 163, in update_post_from_soup
    post_company = card.find("span", {"class": "company"}).find("a").decode_contents().replace("\u2026", "...")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Line 163 mentioned in the trace *is* the line in the try block. So it raised an AttributeError because there was no `<a></a>` tag within the `<span>`. I get that. But why didn't my `except` block catch this and execute the alternative line? Isn't `except AttributeError` handling precisely that error msg?

As [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460189/python-try-except-not-working) says: "The except clause will only catch exceptions that are raised inside of their corresponding try block". So yeah, it should've caught it, no?

Comment: You're not only using ```.find()``` to find 'a'. You're also using it in ```card.find()``` That's the error that it's throwing here. Your card object is here ```None``` which is why it's throwing this error.

Comment: So wait: my except block has ```card.find("span", {"class": "company"}).decode_contents().replace("\u2026", "...")``` which caused the AttributeError (on line 165). But the "Traceback" info still points to line 163? I don't get it.

Comment: you have duplicate .find calls in 'card.find("span", {"class": "company"}).find("a")'  so you can get this error in couple of ways: 1 - card was None, 2 - card.find(..) was None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually catches it, but your 'except' block generates anoter one.

Comment: the 'card' is None, you need to check why

Comment: Ohhh, thats why. I didn't consider that my "card" variable could be None. Thanks guys

Comment: Please see my comment re: 'But the "Traceback" info still points to line 163? I don't get it.' This is saying the AttributeError happened on line 165 within the ```except``` block, but the trace points to the line prior? Is it just not intelligent enough to follow the program thru the ```except``` block, into the ```except``` block's card.find() and highlight line 165 for me? Reply appreciated, it would teach me some nuance about the stack trace.

Comment: Without going into details - your code structure is bad. Instead of using single 'post_company' variable, you will be better off using separate 'post_company_tag' for keeping the HTML element, and split the code to multiple rows. Example pseudo-code: 1. pc_tag = card.find(..) | 2. if not pc_tag: raise/continue ... | 3. if pc_tag.a: pc_tag = pc_tag.a | 4. post_company = pc_tag.decode..|  Hope this helped.